# Standard way to wait for all tasks to finish before exiting

Tags: ray

I was wondering - is there a straightforward way to wait for all tasks to finish running before exiting without keeping track of all the `ObjectID`s (and `get()`ing them)? Use case is when I launch `@remote`s for saving output, for example, where there is no return result needed. It's just extra stuff to keep track of if I have to store those futures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no standard way to block until all tasks have finished.

There are some **workarounds** that can be used.

1. Keep track of all of the object IDs in a list `object_ids` and then call `ray.get(object_ids)` or `ray.wait(object_ids, num_returns=len(object_ids))`.
2. Loop as long as some resources are being used.

   ```
   import time

   while (ray.global_state.cluster_resources() !=
          ray.global_state.available_resources()):
       time.sleep(1)
   ```

   The above code will loop until it detects that no tasks are currently being executed. However this is not a foolproof approach. It's possible that there could be a moment in time when no tasks are running but a scheduler a task is about to start running.

Comment: Thanks. Do you think such a feature might be implemented in the future? 


Based on your 2) snippet, I'm guessing if you're using Ray as a way to run directed, acyclic graphs, if your code is written in serial as: `init(); thingthatsubmitsremotes_1(); thingthatsubmitsremotes_2(); ...; sleepforabit(); entersleeploop()`, since Ray is so fast at scheduling tasks, if the initial sleep time is >> the milliseconds-ish timescale of task scheduling, this snippet would rarely exit because a task was not scheduled yet?

Comment: I think the semantics need to be defined a little more precisely. For example, what happens if a task already executed on a machine but then the machine died? What if a task can't execute because it has a resource requirement that isn't satisfied by any of the nodes? In Ray, there isn't really a central list of all the tasks that have been executed (there is, but it could be stale). Given the subtleties, I think it makes sense to let the application handle it for now. However, for simple non-edge cases, I think the hacks above should usually work.